# Modeling number of spectators in football

Tags: regression, machine-learning, categorical-data, games, many-categories

Can anyone give ideas on the possible best way forward to solve this specific machine learning problem for sports analytics?

Data set looks like:

```
HomeTeam             AwayTeam                NoOfSpectators
AC Milan             FC Barcelona              56900
Real Madrid          Bayern Munchen            78900
```

The outcome variable is `NoOfSpectators` but there are many levels in both `HomeTeam` and `AwayTeam`.

There are about 50 levels in both HomeTeam and AwayTeam. I know you can do OneHot encoding or Label encoding but what other options are worth trying?

For example use RandomForest or LightGBM that can automatically handle categorical / factor variable?

Also since for example:
HomeTeam             AwayTeam                NoOfSpectators
AC Milan             FC Barcelona              56900

is the same as:
HomeTeam             AwayTeam                NoOfSpectators
FC Barcelona         AC Milan                  56900

How do you suggest that the data set should be structured / modeled before input to a ML model?

Comment: Welcome to CV! Could you edit your question to include what you have tried so far? It is not clear to me why many categorical features would be a problem. Is your sample size perhaps too small? In case you are asking how to do the entire analysis, I'm afraid your question is off-topic.

Comment: How many different levels in `HomeTeam` and `AwayTeam`?  You might find some help in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146907/principled-way-of-collapsing-categorical-variables-with-many-levels   (maybe a duplicate)

Comment: Updated my question as I wasn't very clear

Comment: Surely " AC Milan Barcelona FC" and "Barcelona FC AC Milan" are different matches at different venues, so why would the attendance be the same for both ?

Comment: You should try a better title like "Modeling number of spectators in football"

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas for modeling:  You should definitely not start with some complicated black-box model like RandomForest, you should start with simpler models like linear models which can give some understanding (and serve as a reference if you later decide to try RandomForest etc).

But I think you should start with a better variable encoding. A linear additive model like `~ \text{HomeTeam} + \text{AwayTeam}` will not really use the information that A is Home and B is Away, since A+B = B+A. Adding an interaction term will not change that. So you need a better encoding. Add a third variable `HomeStadion`, which you can code from the information that you have. Then you can try a model like 
$$
     \text{NoOfSpectators} = \beta_0+ \beta_1 \text{HomeStadion} + \beta_2 \text{HomeTeam} +\beta_3 \text{AwayTeam} + \epsilon
$$
or you could try to include an interaction term ($\beta_1$ can be interpreted as "HomeTeam advantage"). But with an interaction term the number of parameters will be very large (about 50x50=2500) so will need very large sample size, or you must use regularization.  See the discussion in [Principled way of collapsing categorical variables with many levels?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146907/principled-way-of-collapsing-categorical-variables-with-many-levels).  It could maybe be useful to use different penalization's for main effects and interactions? It could be that the most important effect of interaction is an "star meeting" effect, so most interaction parameters could be close to zero. That could be represented via lasso, giving sparsity, while the additive parameter could use ridge penalty.

```
EDIT
```

answer to new question in comments: The factor variables should be represented by dummy variables, which can be used directly. Good software should construct the dummys for you. But, if you use regularization, note that you should **not** leave out one "reference level" as usually is done, as it **changes the model when regularization is done**. See  [Dropping one of the columns when using one-hot encoding](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231285/dropping-one-of-the-columns-when-using-one-hot-encoding/329281#329281)

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible to use factor variables directly in linear regression? Or what would you suggest is the best way to encode the variable if you have, say, 75 unique values in HomeTeam?

Comment: Besides OneHot encoding the team names, you can have a look at neural network embeddings. They will probably capture much more information compared to OHE.

Comment: @Stergios: Certainly you can do that, but it is a good strategy to first build a simple, logical, interpretable model, at least as a baseline.

Comment: Sure, I totally agree with that. I just mentioned an idea for possible further improvement.