# meaning of drop in OneHotEncoder

Tags: scikit-learn, categorical-encoding

I am having a tough time as a newbie understanding the `drop` argument in `OneHotEncoder`. Does it drop the column with the non-numerical values of the categorical variables after it is done?

I am looking at the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder) and I don't get how we end up with a `2 x 3` array at the end.

```
>>> enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
>>> X = [['Male', 1], ['Female', 3], ['Female', 2]]


... 


>>> drop_enc = OneHotEncoder(drop='first').fit(X)
>>> drop_enc.categories_
[array(['Female', 'Male'], dtype=object), array([1, 2, 3], dtype=object)]
>>> drop_enc.transform([['Female', 1], ['Male', 2]]).toarray()
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0.]])
```

I was expecting 5 columns :

- 1 column for male,
- 1 column for female,
- 1 column for the 1 category
- 1 column for the 2 category
- 1 column for the 3 category

Answer (score 3):

Implementation-wise, the `drop` keyword results in one category per column being dropped. Thus, out of `['Female', 'Male']`, `Female` is dropped, and out of `[1, 2, 3]`, `1` is dropped. This leads to the format that you've printed, but for clarity, let's write out some column names.

Suppose your original features are called "biological sex," which (for this example) is `['Female', 'Male']`, and "ID", which is `[1, 2, 3]`. Your output is equivalent to the table:

| **bio. sex is Male** | **ID is 2** | **ID is 3** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |

which corresponds to `['Female', 1]` and `['Male', 2]` as expected. Note that the columns **bio. sex is Female** and **ID is 1** are omitted by design.

To get the 5-column output you expect, simply remove the `drop` keyword.

There are [many reasons why one would or would not choose to drop one feature per (original) column](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231285/dropping-one-of-the-columns-when-using-one-hot-encoding). In short, if all features for a column are one-hot encoded, then the encoded features are now multicollinear (i.e., a linear combination of other features), which may or may not result in ill-defined estimators (e.g., non-regularized OLS). I am glossing over an incredible amount of nuance -- I would carefully read the linked answer to learn more.